# Inserting row with foreign key relation in same transaction as primary row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a 2 tables where one has a foreign key relation to the other

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  value VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  foo_key INT NOT NULL
  value VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

I'm using parameterized ADO.NET ExecuteReader to Insert new rows. My pickle is, if I want to insert 2 rows in different tables in the same transaction, i.e. before commit, I cannot insert rows in bar since I don't know the value that has been given foo.id yet. How would you go about doing that? i.e. How do I make sure that bar.foo_key get assigned the right value? Trying to select on it brings nothing, since I guess it is not actually there yet. Should I use a stored procedure to try and generate the key on the fly, or maybe there is an internal variable that can be used. Or is there a way to have the insert return the new id? Do I need a foreign key declaration, though I'm not sure that would be useful since again I still don't know what id to use?

The reason why I want to do it in one go, is due to error handling, I want to be able to roll everything back in case of an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `scope_identity()` to retrieve the newly generated `identity`:

```
begin tran;
insert Foo (value) values ('6*7');
declare @fk int = scope_identity();
insert bar (foo_key, value) values (@fk, '42');
commit tran;
```

Per HLGEM's comment, to return the value of the newly generated identity to the client, you can use `output`:

```
insert Foo (value) output inserted.ID values ('6*7');
```

Note that for a transaction to span two sessions, you need a distributed transaction, which is very expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!

Comment: Can I assume this would require the inserts to occur in the same session, i.e. same ExecuteReader Command, or does it persist per connection to the db? I have a UnitOfWork within the DAL code, which carries a persistent db connection, the transation is tied to that entity in the client code, the inserts occur in different ExecuteReader Commands.

Comment: Or you can preferably use the output clause.

Comment: Yeah, `scope_identity()` is limited to the same session.  You could use the `output` clause, like HLGEM suggests, to have an `ExecuteReader` return the newly inserted identity to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can return scope_identity() on the insert

```
INSERT INTO [foo] ([value]) VALUES (@0) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Scope_Identity() will return the current identity within the same scope, which means the same tranaction. If you happen to have the script runs in different transaction, you can't get it using scope_identity. If that happens, you can use insert...output inserted.id into another table, and next time you look up from the table.